# Add a foreign key to an existing table

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have a created table I would like to add another foreign key to.

```
create table serie(

    time char(8),
    result varchar(2),
    mnr varchar(2),
    primary key(time, mnr),
    foreign key(mnr) references Target(mnr)

)engine=innodb;
```

This is the table as it is now.

I would like to add another key to another table. Is the best solution to remove the table and just recreate it with the new key or is it possible to just update it?

Comment: I take it [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) didn't have anything to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this.

```
  ALTER TABLE serie
  ADD CONSTRAINT result FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
     REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(id);
```

Comment: Maby I should have provided the key I wanted to add. Because I'm a little unsure of how I should use that. The key is "pnr" and the table is "Shooter". What is "result", "UserID" and "ActiveDirectories(id);"?